# How to add forms dynamically to a Django formset?

Tags: python, django, formset

i cannot able to understand how create_book_normal() works in this code.

```
def create_book_normal(request):
    template_name = 'store/create_normal.html'
    heading_message = 'Formset Demo'

if request.method == 'GET':
    formset = BookFormset(request.GET or None)
elif request.method == 'POST':
    formset = BookFormset(request.POST)
    if formset.is_valid():
        for form in formset:
            name = form.cleaned_data.get('name')
            myuser = form.cleaned_data.get('myuser')
            # save book instance
            if name:
                Book(name=name,myuser=myuser).save()
```

please explain me how this redirect works. #store:book_list

```
        return redirect('store:book_list')

return render(request, template_name, {
    'formset': formset,
    'heading': heading_message,
})
```

how values are getting stored in the store:book_list?

if i change book to Book then it shows eror like this - NoReverseMatch at /store/book/create_normal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling `redirect('store:book_list')` Django is performing a reverse lookup of the `'book-list'` url in the `store` namespace.

Look within your Django project and see if there is an application named `store` and within it a `urls.py` file. You should see an `urlpattern` where `name='book_list'`. The redirect will then run the view in that urlpattern.

Check out the [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls) on django urls